# Issue while angular project update from 4 to 6

Tags: angular

I am updating my current project from angular 4 version to 6. I followed the steps mentioned in this URL: https://update.angular.io/

I reached up to `ng update @angular/core` where I am facing issues with dependencies. I get the following errors:-

[image]

Comment: As suggested can you please run your console as an adminstrator?

Comment: Try to run your comand line as an Administrator , could be file permissions!